In what work did Venn use his diagrams to analyze syllogisms?
In what work did Venn first use his diagrams to analyze syllogisms?
cf. the diagrams here

The Encyclopedia Britannica entry on John Venn states that it was in his 1881 text Symbolic Logic.

I skimmed through Symbolic Logic, and I could only find a few Venn-like diagrams toward the end.

If memory serves, they're called Euler diagrams after Leonard Euler, the mathematician.


John Venn (1834-1923), Symbolic Logic (1881), ch. 5 "Diagrammatic Representation", pp. 100-125.

For an earlier Venn's pubblication, see:

On the diagrammatic and mechanical representation of propositions and reasonings (Phil.Mag, 1880).

See also

Amirouche Moktefi & Jens Lemanski, On the Origin of Venn Diagrams (Axiomathes, 2022)

For Euler, see

Letters of Euler to a German princess, on different subjects in physics and philosophy (1791), p. 397 ff.

Brief and useful:

Frank Thomas Sautter, A Bunch of Diagrammatic Methods for Syllogistics (Logica Universalis, 2019)

